# Wordpress - avoid opening php files as pages?

Tags: wordpress

I have some php scripts in my Wordpress directory and I'm unable to use them. Why? Because Wordpress treat them as posts.

For example:

http://kaptinlin.com/themes/striking/wp-content/themes/striking/includes/sendmail.php

Points to a file and it works.

But on my site when i try to open /wp-content/themes/myTheme/anyDictionary/anyfile.php

it loads:

```
    Not Found

Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.
```

Page.

How to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The default WordPress `mod_rewrite` rules look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

In essence, this says "pass all requests through WordPress, unless the request corresponds to a real file or directory." So, if you're seeing a WordPress delivered page when you expect the output of a non-WordPress script:

1. Your rewrite rules differ from the default; paste them for help debugging. Or,
2. The file may not exist where you think it does.

Comment: Is there a way to check my these rules for my Wordpress? I'm sure I haven't changed them, but who knows...

Comment: These rules are most commonly located in the .htaccess file in your WordPress directory.

Comment: Thank you. My file looks like that: 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress